# Are there things unworthy of being eaten?

Tags: food

The tag [food](/questions/tagged/food) has a description of "Anything that is worthy of being eaten.". Is there a concept in Islam of something being unworthy of being eaten?

For some people, there'd be things that are unsafe to eat, or where it'd be disrespectful to eat (eating a species that'd be considered [friends, not food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finding_Nemo)), but I haven't considered anything unworthy of being eaten.

Related question: [Are there gods unworthy of worship?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/20046/are-there-gods-unworthy-of-worship)

Comment: I don't know what the author of this tag discription had in mind, but i'd rather replace unworthy by not halal as there are only a few exceptions of things which are haram to eat.

Comment: OP should specify if he needs the list of foods or he needs things (to do or eat) that are unsafe while/for eating.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are *halal* foods and *haram* foods. Halal foods are worthy of being eaten while it is forbidden to eat haram foods and so they are unworthy of being eaten.

> وكلوا مما رزقكم الله **حلالا طيبا**
>
> And eat of what Allah has provided for you **[which is] lawful and good**.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:88](https://quran.com/5/88)</sup>
>
> ويحل لهم الطيبات **ويحرم عليهم الخبائث**
>
> Makes lawful for them good things, and **makes unlawful for them impure things**
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:157](https://quran.com/7/157)</sup>

There are various things that Muslims are forbidden to eat and drink, such as:

> حرمت عليكم الميتة والدم ولحم الخنزير وما أهل لغير الله به
>
> Prohibited to you are dead animals, blood, the flesh of swine, and that which has been dedicated to other than Allah
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:3](https://quran.com/5/3)</sup>
>
> ميتة أو دما مسفوحا أو لحم خنزير فإنه رجس
>
> a dead animal or blood spilled out or the flesh of swine - for indeed, it is impure
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:145](https://quran.com/6/145?translations=84) Also see [Quran 2:173](https://quran.com/2/173)</sup>
>
> ولا تأكلوا مما لم يذكر اسم الله عليه
>
> And do not eat of that upon which the name of Allah has not been mentioned
>
> <sup>—  [Quran 6:121](https://quran.com/6/121)</sup>
>
> يا أيها الذين آمنوا إنما الخمر والميسر والأنصاب والأزلام رجس من عمل الشيطان فاجتنبوه لعلكم تفلحون
>
> O you who believe! Wine, gambling, altars and divining arrows are filth, made up by Satan. Therefore, refrain from it, so that you may be successful.
>
> <sup>—  [Quran 5:90](https://quran.com/5/90) Also see [Quran 2:219](https://quran.com/2/219)</sup>

Haram foods have been called خبائث and رجس (impure, evil, filthy, abhorent) and the act of eating haram foods has been called or implied to be فسق , بَاغٍ , إثم , عَادٍ   (grave disobedience, transgression and sin).

Answer (score 0):

I think saying `Unworthy to eat` directs me to foods those are [makruh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makruh).

1. [God's right] Foods those are [makruh in Islam](http://www.eat-halal.com/makruh/).
2. [Self's right] Foods those I eat when I don't need them and those are harmful to me, like eating foods those have sausage when I know eating sausage is harmful to me.
3. [People's right] In my society eating foods those are not good among them -A cause of making others upset-.